# Criar atalho para comandos complexos no CMD

Tags: cmd

Utilizo o comando `taskkill /f /im nome.exe` para parar processos,
pois o mesmo para todos os processos com o mesmo nome.

> Gostaria de incurtar esse comando para algo como `tk nome.exe`.

Tentei criar uma variavel de ambiente, até funcionou, mas tenho
que digitar dessa forma:

`%tk% nome.exe`

Como posso criar esse atalho de comando?

Comment: Não compensa simplesmente criar um link no seu path, ou mesmo um bat para ficar permanente? algo como tk.bat ou tk.cmd com conteúdo @echo off  \n taskkill /f /im %1 - acho mais prático do que usar um doskey e ter que fazer script de inicialização pra persistir

Comment: você pode criar um arquivo batch que receba o nome como parâmetro e execute o comando

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou dar um exemplo bem simples, que não dependerá de nenhum programa externo:

1. Crie uma pasta em um lugar especifico, por exemplo `C:\meus_comandos`
2. Vá até o Computador e clique com o direito do mouse (rato) e então selecione propriedades:

   [image: pc propriedades]
3. Clique em configurações avançadas do sistema:

   [image: configurações avançadas]
4. Clica em variaveis de ambiente

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Selecione PATH e clique em <kbd>Editar...</kbd>

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. Clica em novo:

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai ser liberada a opção de digitar, então escreva:

```
C:\meus_comandos
```

### Criando os comandos:

Agora na pasta `meus_comandos` você poderá criar quantos arquivos `.bat` quiser e eles serão reconhecidos como comandos, crie na pasta um arquivo com o nome `tk.bat` e adicione este conteúdo:

```
@echo off

taskkill /f /im %1
```

Depois abra o cmd em qualquer pasta e digite isto:

```
tk nome.exe
```

Comment: não sabia que dava pra fazer desse modo, obrigado Guilherme !

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um alias para o seu comando utilizando o [DOSKEY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490894(v=technet.10))

Basta criar um arquivo em qualquer diretório, por exemplo:

C:\Users\TomMelo\Documents\macros.doskey

```
print=echo $*
```

Depois basta adicionar um uma regkey para tornar o alias disponível toda vez que você estiver usando o cmd:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /d "doskey /macrofile=\"C:\Users\TomMelo\Documents\macros.doskey\"" /f
```

Feche o cmd e abra uma nova sessão, seu alias já deve ficar disponível.
Pra mais opções sobre parâmetros dê uma olhada [aqui](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) também.

Comment: Interessante Tom, obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 2):

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### A variável **`Path`** tem limitações de comprimento de caracteres...

**1)** Por se tratar de um **`Bat`** que não apaga/remove algum arquivo ou pasta, você pode adicionar esse **`Bat`** na pasta do **`Windows`**, assim aproveitando que essa pasta já tem o seu caminho completo salvo na **variável** **`Path`**, e ainda, nenhuma **ação/configuração adicional será necessária** para isso funcionar, igualmente sem esbarrar em algum problema de limitação, devido a erros reportados sobre a variável **`Path`**, (comentado/lincados no **item 2**).

- > Para isso, é necessário executar o **<kbd>`cmd.exe`</kbd>** como **<kbd>`administrador:`</kbd>**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O comando para criar o **`Bat`** para esse fim, seria:

**<kbd>`echo/@echo off ^& taskkill /f /im "%~1" %2>"%windir%\tk.cmd"`</kbd>**

> Após isso feito, basta digitar em qualquer **`drive:\pasta o comando`**:

- **<kbd>`tk chrome.exe /t`</kbd>**
- **<kbd>`tk firefox.exe`</kbd>**
- **<kbd>`tk qualquer.exe`</kbd>**

---

**Obs.: 1)** O **parâmetro/argumento** **<kbd>`%2`</kbd>**  pode vir a ser ou não usado, mas em si, este informa ao **`taskkill.exe`** para finalizar também algum **processo filho** criado/iniciado pelo executável a ser finalizar. Tem vezes que é útil quando algum plugin "buga/trava" ao finalizar o navegado (exemplo).

**Obs.: 2)** Muitos desenvolvedores/fornecedores de software/drives/componentes, como por exemplo a **Nvidia**, também usam a pasta **Windows** para manter alguns **Bats**, e executá-los quando necessário sem adicionar/acrescentar mais pastas/caminhos na variável de ambiente **`Path´**.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

- [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**2)** Ao usar uma pasta especifica para manter e executar um ou mais **`bats`**, será necessário a adição do caminho dessa pasta na variável global **`Path`**.

**Obs.:** È possível usar as instruções presentes na resposta do operador **<kbd>[`@Guilherme Nascimento`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento)</kbd>**, ou ainda, usar o comando **`SetX`** para configurar esse valor, de maneira que será possível visualizar na execução/saída, qualquer ocorrência de **erro/aviso**: **<kbd>`setx /M Path "%Path%;c:\Pasta_BATs"`</kbd>**

- > Para isso, também é necessário executar o **<kbd>`cmd.exe`</kbd>** como **<kbd>`administrador:`</kbd>**

---

### **Considere**

Apenas para perceber possível **`aviso/erro`** na execução do comando, **visto haver problemas reportados** por usuários, devido a um **limite no comprimento de caracteres** dos valores atribuídos à variável **`Path`**.

- Postagens comentando/abordando a **limitação**:

**<kbd>[`StackOverFlow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10)</kbd> Environment Variable is too large on Windows 10 # 38632 Visitas**

**<kbd>[`SuperUser`](https://superuser.com/questions/1070272/why-does-windows-have-a-limit-on-environment-variables-at-all)</kbd> Why does Windows have a limit on environment variables at all? # 13215 Visitas**

**<kbd>[`YouTube`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EmLTsRTWUI)</kbd> Solved - Environment or User PATH Variable length limitation # 643 Visitas**

**<kbd>[`Intel`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/limitation-to-the-length-of-the-system-path-variable)</kbd> Limitation to the length of the System PATH variable #  Não informa Visitas**

---

- > Ao executar o comando **`SetX`**, recebi o **aviso**:
- > **"os dados são truncados em 1024 caracteres ao serem salvos."**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> O comprimento em caracteres na minha variável **`Path`** foi **1412** caracteres antes de adicionar/editar a variável, e o número de pastas presentes nela foram **32**.
>
> Após adicionar a pasta  **`c:\Pasta_BATs`**, a contagem de caracteres caiu para **1185**, e o número de pastas foi para **28**?.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Então, temos uma divergências de informações da interface gráfica e na linha de comando, qual a mais precisa?
>
> Os valores da variável **`Path`** no ambiente de console/linha de comando, são caminhos (completos) de pastas, divididas pelo delimitador **`;`**.
>
> Os valores da variável **`Path`** na interface de **Configurações Avançadas do Sistema**, são exibidos em uma listagem de caminho e pastas, um item por linha, sem delimitador.

---

### **Conclusão**

- > Perdeu-se algumas pastas após adicionar o valor **`c:\Pasta_BATs`** na variável **`Path`**, então considerei usar a pasta do **Windows** para os **`Bats`** meus bats, é mais simples, como também fazem alguns fabricantes de componentes/drivers/softers/etc..
- > Para os que preferem usar essa variável, adicionando mais caminhos á variável **`Path`**, recomendo assistir o vídeo do link **[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EmLTsRTWUI)**, lembrando que há comentário na passagem citando não ser **possível/realizável** no **Windows 10** os passos mostrados na publicação, dado ao fato que, a exibição na interface gráfica é seccionada em uma listagem, não é uma exibição do conteúdo completo com um delimitador, apenas listagem de valor individual.

---